# Using RVest package to scrape ReactJS site

Tags: reactjs, rvest

I'm having trouble scraping a site that is built on ReactJS, since the HTML is loaded via JS. I'm hoping to stick to R, using Rvest, but can use Python as well.

Pressing ctrl-U to see the html source does not show what is loaded on the page. Whereas, going into developer tools on Chrome (F12), I can see all the components under source.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: u will need to use headless parser with this. hope this link will help you https://www.r-bloggers.com/web-scraping-javascript-rendered-sites/

Comment: Thanks! Using PhantomJS to download the webpage into an HTML file worked well.